# TightVNC problem connecting to iPod

Tags: ipod-touch, vnc

I have been trying to use TightVNC viewer with Veency ipod service to view my ipods screen on my computer. I can only connect to the ipod after it has been rebooted, it seems like if it has been running for a bit I cannot connect. I know that the IP address of my Ipod sometimes changes after I reboot (i'm using connectify to connect), but I always make sure to check the new IP.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Veency/TightVNC combo for a while now to control my iPhone from the computer. I never have issues with it connecting. Do you use SBSettings by any chance? If you do, instead of rebooting you could try this:

1. Open SBSettings by swiping across the top bar (with the carrier/time/battery/etc...)
2. Click on the "More" button
3. Click on "Mobile Substrate Addons"
4. Toggle Veency Off
5. Press the Home Button
6. Repeat 1-5 but toggle Veency On

It's a pain in the butt but definitely takes less time than restarting the phone. You could also try respringing the phone when Veency stops working and see if that fixes it, that would be a pretty quick solution.

What else do you have running on the phone that uses your internet connection and is a jailbroken app? There could be something that interferes with VNC.

Comment: I do use SBSettings. I have push notifications for Mail enabled, and two-way Push calendar with my google calendar. Only mail shows up under the Processes list

Comment: It won't show up under the Processes list. When VNC stops working try respringing the phone and see if it comes back to life. To respring, bring up SBSettings and click on "Respring"

Comment: I understand that it wouldn't show up in processes. It was just additional information. Respringing fixed it. Why does it happen?

Comment: I'm not sure why it is happening. It could be a variety of things. There could be other software trying to use the VNC port. Something might be killing the Veency server. There might have been another program you installed that messed up the Veency installation. Try uninstalling and reinstalling Veency. If that that doesn't fix it, you might be able to look through the crash logs on the iPod. That might be more cryptic though as sometimes the problem is too ambiguous. This is the one problem I have with programs made for the Jailbroken device. They have full access and mess stuff up sometimes.